# Initialize LiveData In AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am looking for a way to initialize the LiveData object inside the ViewModel. Items are currently only getting initialized when setQuery method is called from the activity.

```
public class MyListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private final LiveData <List<Item>> items;
private final MutableLiveData<String> query = new MutableLiveData<>();


private MyDatabase db;

public MyListViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    db  = MyDatabase.getInstance(application);
    items = Transformations.switchMap(query, (search)->{
        if (search == null || search.trim().length() == 0) {
            return db.itemDao().getAllItems();
        } else {
            return db.itemDao().findItemsBySearchTerm(search);
        }
    });

}

public LiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setQuery(String queryText) {
   query.setValue(queryText);
}
```

}

Comment: try calling the `setQuery("")` below items  transformation initialization, so you can avoid initial call from Activity

Answer (score 6):

You have to **call** `setQuery(String queryText)` **at least once**
As per Transformation documentation

> The transformations **aren't calculated** unless an observer is observing the returned LiveData object.
>   Because the transformations are calculated **lazily**, lifecycle-related behavior is implicitly passed down without requiring additional explicit calls or dependencies.

So that if you don't call `setQuery(String queryText)` from Activity it will not update `MutableLiveData<String> query` and will not trigger the Transformation.

If you want to **avoid** initial call from Activity you can call it below the Transformation initialization like this,

```
public MyListViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    db  = MyDatabase.getInstance(application);
    items = Transformations.switchMap(query, (search)->{
        if (search == null || search.trim().length() == 0) {
            return db.itemDao().getAllItems();
        } else {
            return db.itemDao().findItemsBySearchTerm(search);
        }
    });
    setQuery("")
}
```

It will trigger the empty search part and will return **All Items**.

Also you need to **observe** the returned data in your case `items`. If no observer is observing the data then Transaction will not trigger.

As I referred from [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html) and few Blogs this worked for me

Comment: Is this worked for you? Seems no other answers so you can approve this one :)